# Tool to check the impact of web browser updates on HTML content?

Tags: html, software-testing

I create eLearning packages that publish to HTML5. Occasionally there are issues when new browser versions are rolled out, usually rendering issues. I want to catch these automatically.

What is the best tool to capture a series of actions on a web page, record the screen shots, then replay the actions at a later time and highlight any differences? In other words, I want something to tell me if anything visual has changed.

Some of the content is hosted in cloud based system and I would also like to use the same scripts/captures to test if upgrades to that platform have any impact on the content's functionality.

I don't mind if I have to record separate scripts/tests for each of the browsers, that's OK as there are rendering differences between IE, Edge & Chrome.

Ideally the tool would work on mobile, but that's not essential.

I have investigated some Selenium based tools and framework but they seem like overkill. I just need a simple screen-diffing tool at the end of the day.

Ideally I'm looking for something that people with no programming/scripting skills could use once it is setup and configured.

Surely there must be something out there?

David